# Clean Architecture: How to notify presentation layer of a data change in the data layer

Tags: flutter, design-patterns, architecture, clean-architecture

I am studying the popular Clean Architecture as proposed by Uncle Bob as
I am trying to find a good architecture for a new app I am about to start developing in Flutter/Dart.

I have also looked at the pictured design proposal by Resocoder: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0Xfm.png)

My question is: In this design proposal by Resocoder, how does the UI get a notification about a data change in a data source made from outside of the app ui? I.e. a data change made by the API in the lower left corner.

I am wondering if this design is just not supporting this scenario.

Comment: To actively listen for changes from API, you need to have a StreamListener

Comment: @Prashant: Thank you for your answer. So if using BLoCs in the ui, it could be a stream of entities from a data source to a BLoC?

Comment: Any consumer of a RiverPod provider gets notified when that provider changes values.  That could depend on other providers, or streams, or futures being completed.  RiverPod is specifically designed to have the view layer informed by the model layer in a consistent and scalable manner.